# How to show terminal output in panel?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, gnome, gnome-shell

I have a little bash script which simply outputs the currently playing song (from Clementine) via dbus. I'd like this output somewhere visible on my desktop at all times, i.e in a panel or a small always on top (transparent) window.

My first thought was to write a Gnome-Shell extension (just the desktop environment I'm currently using, but am open to other suggestions) which would run this command every 5 seconds or so. Is there a better/easier way to do this?

Comment: Are you aware that there is a MPRIS extension that should be compatible with Clementine: https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/55/media-player-indicator/ ?

Comment: I am, but am looking for something that is always visible :)

Comment: I really thought it could be made to do that -- to show the name of the song on the panel. Maybe I'm wrong. If that is the case I suggest you modify the extension to do that: that should be the easiest route by far.

Comment: No it looks like you were right, I just assumed it was an equivalent of the old gnome-panel sound applet and didn't investigate further. Thanks for the heads up! (Will tick an actual answer if you want)